# Send an email if an Item is older than 7 days workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have a SP2010 site with a list that records each persons weekly update. If the personb doesn't update their entry after 7 days I want them to get an email. I created a reminder field that calculates the reminder date from last modified date. Then use a workflow to check that the Reminder 7 day date hasn't passed.

> ```
> Example:
> Last modified date- 01/04/2015
> Reminder7d date - 08/04/2015
> ```

```
Workflow - set to start when an item is updated:
If Current Item:Reminder 7d equals Today
    Email username
```

But it doesn't seem to work for the 20 items I have in my list? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This workflow is not triggering as you set this to on item updated. But since item is not updating at all the workflow is not getting triggerd. See my answer below,

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint designer, you can use "Pause for duration" or "Pause until date" action in your workflow. Using this action workflow will wait till that duration and then it will trigger. Set workflow to run when item added and item updated.

For example you can refer [this link](http://prasadtechtactics.blogspot.in/2012/07/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-part.html).

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @ps. You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow that uses "Pause for duration" action, setting its value as 7 days.

When we add an item in a list/library, the date columns "Created" and "Modified" are always same unless you update the item. After an item update "Modified" date column is updated. Your workflow will trigger on item creation and will remain pause for 7 days. After 7 days it will check if "Created" and "Modified" are equal, if yes then that means for past 7 days the item is not being modified and then it would trigger an email to "Created by".

Set your workflow to run on item creation and item change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this blog, you can write the mail-address to the log,

Declare duedate =29/02/2016 & minus 7 days stored in date variable

[Please click Here](http://peakfinders.blogspot.in/2016/02/before-days-send-reminder-mail.html)